# how to do pagination for custom controller in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to do pagination for the custom controller but i facing issue for next button.here is code for controller::

```
public class viewCustomerNew
{
public String cc1 { get; set; }
public List <customer__c> custm{get; set;}
public string cid1;
Integer limitSize = 10;
Integer totalSize =0; 
public List <customer__c> custm3{get; set;}
public List <customer__c> ContactsToShow{get; set;}

public viewCustomerNew()
{
  beginning();
}

public  void beginning()
{
     List<customer__c> ContactsToShow = new List<customer__c>();
     custm = [Select ID,ADDRESS_1__c,ADDRESS_2__c,AGE__c,EMAILID__c,PHONENO__c from customer__c limit 10 ];

     totalSize = custm.size();
     System.debug('list element' +totalSize);


}

public Boolean getDisablePrevious()
{
        if(counter == 0)
            return true ;
        else
            return false ;
} 

public  void next()
{
 counter = 0;
 List<customer__c> ContactsToShow = new List<customer__c>();
 custm = [Select ID,ADDRESS_1__c,ADDRESS_2__c,AGE__c,EMAILID__c,PHONENO__c from customer__c ORDER BY ID limit 10 OFFSET 10];
 System.debug('this is value of next method' +custm);    


}  
}
```

Here is my VF code.

```
<apex:page controller="viewCustomerNew" showChat="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!custm}" var="cs" >
                <apex:column headerValue="age" value="{!cs.AGE__c}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="<" action="{!beginning}" />
                <apex:commandButton value=">" action="{!next}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? And Was there any specific reason to avoid   StandardSetController+Extension ?

Comment: its not showing next 10 records after clicking next button.

Comment: Post VF code as well. Are you rerendering the Table after the Next method call?

Comment: <apex:page controller="viewCustomerNew" showChat="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
   
   <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:form >

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!custm}" var="cs">                      <apex:column headerValue="age" value="{!cs.AGE__c}"/>                     <apex:commandButton value="<" action="{!beginning}" />

<apex:commandButton value= ">" action="{!next}"  />                                 </apex:form>
 </apex:pageBlock>
       
 </apex:page>

Answer (score 2):

As I could see from your code. You are not rerendering the data back into VF. Please do so as seen in my below VF code.

```
<apex:page controller="viewCustomerNew" showChat="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:pageBlock id="tablePB">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!custm}" var="cs" id="tableID">
            <apex:column headerValue="age" value="{!cs.AGE__c}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="<" action="{!beginning}" />
            <apex:commandButton value=">" action="{!next}" rerender="tablePB"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Mean while the logic for Pagination is flawed and hard coded.
You can refer below link to properly create a custom pagination controller and VF.
http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/12/custom-controller-pagination-with.html